Visualforce does not display image from formula field
We have a visualforce page that displays a image formula field:
<apex:outputText value="{!pp.ERPvs__Producto__r.Imagen_chica__c}" escape="false" />

This is the output value of the field:
<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00Pal00000GXKI5EAP" alt=" " style="height:40px; width:40px;" border="0"/>

The record layout displays the image properly:

But the visualforce fails to render the image:

This only happens in one org, in other orgs it works fine. These images are stored as attachments in the record itself.Any ideas? The link works fine and the image does exist.
